# strange playback from AKSamplePlayer

Tags: audiokit

I am getting very strange playback from an AKSamplePlayer from wav files (tried various). It plays for a while and then speeds up playback always at the same point. Is this a known issue, I'm thinking to do with the length of the the file maybe. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried testing the file using something like AVAudioPlayer to make sure it's not an anomaly in the file?

Comment: This is not a known issue, but I'd like to get to the bottom of it if you can provide a github project demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Hi Aurelius I am sending a link to my code because then it will keep the wav file I have etc, if you could take a look that would be great. I have checked the file in AKAudioPlayer and it plays fine, I have also tried out a lot of different files with similar results. The code is a bit all over the place because I am trying stuff out, so apologies. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5uqlgvrxxtohgal/audioPlayerV3.zip?dl=0

Comment: Aurelius the change happens after about a minute.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the SKSamplePlayer in the most basic config I can and still the problem persists, audio speeds up, slows down with many different codecs etc, seems like their is probably an issue with the sample player class.

Comment: I meant AKSamplePlayer sorry for the typo.